# Possible for an Android App take up whole screen

Tags: android, android-fullscreen

I am in middle of app development and what I want it that when user powers up his/her phone and the home screen loads, can there be a broadcast (from system) which could fire an app to launch and take up the whole screen?

**Is is possible to do this ?**

Further, can this also be done via some background service, when the app wants, it should display and take full screen of user. Can this be done also ?

**What would I need to do for this ?**

Answer (score 0):

Up until Android 10, you could register a broadcast for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, and then you could start an Activity from there.

Starting from Andoid 10, there are some restrictions on opening activities from background. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts), there are a few exception that might possibly apply to you ( such as having `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` ).

Note that this kind of behaviour is frowned upon, as it's very intrusive ( some app randomly opening by itself feels like adware app ), so I'd suggest you don't go down this route.